# How to confirm my macro is working?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to get the below script working. I pasted into ThisOutlookSession and have created the appropriate path required (`c:\mails`). I have opened and closed outlook as well.

I have it pasted exactly as below, what am I missing? Is it supposed to show up when I call it using Alt+F8?

Thank you,

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Dim Ns As Outlook.NameSpace
  Set Ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set Items = Ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
  If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.MailItem Then
    SaveMailAsFile Item
  End If
End Sub

Private Sub SaveMailAsFile(oMail As Outlook.MailItem)
  Dim dtDate As Date
  Dim sName As String
  Dim sFile As String
  Dim sExt As String

  sPath = "c:\mails"
  sExt = ".msg"
  sName = oMail.Subject
  ReplaceCharsForFileName sName, "_"
  dtDate = oMail.ReceivedTime
  sName = Format(dtDate, "yyyymmdd", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, _
    vbUseSystem) & Format(dtDate, "-hhnnss", _
    vbUseSystemDayOfWeek, vbUseSystem) & "-" & sName & sExt

  oMail.SaveAs sPath & sName, olSaveAsMsg
End Sub

Private Sub ReplaceCharsForFileName(sName As String, _
  sChr As String _
)
  sName = Replace(sName, "/", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ":", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "?", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, Chr(34), sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "<", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, ">", sChr)
  sName = Replace(sName, "|", sChr)
End Sub
```

Comment: I meant im using Alt+F8 in the designer view to pull up a list of all the macros.. Except in my case there aren't any macros to select - this being the only one macro im trying. @KlasLindbäck

Comment: None of your Macros is showing up because they are all Private, try using Public Functions and check if they are visible in the Alt+F8 menu

Comment: @buzzin : Just set `SaveMailAsFile` as Public Sub as this most probably your entry point. The rest is called in from inside your module so keeping them private should be an issue.

Comment: @buzzin : My bad, you can keep all of them as Private in fact. But to test that it's working properly, the easiest way would be to put a message before calling `SaveMailAsFile` in `Items_ItemAdd` and then send yourself a mail to see if it triggers your code! ;)

Comment: @R3uK I kept them Private but im still trying to get the message part right. Here is what my code looks like:

`Private Sub Msg_exe()
    MsgBox "The script is working!"
End Sub`

Comment: @buzzin : Did you add a line to call `Msg_exe` in `Items_ItemAdd` inside the If? Because you won't see the message otherwise! ;)

Comment: The code is not designed to be run manually- it's supposed to run automatically when you receive an email-  there is nothing wrong using private sub if all the code are under the same module- now fix your folder Path- sPath = "c:\mails\" you are missing \

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289619

Answer (score 0):

The code is not designed to be run manually- it's supposed to run automatically when you receive an email- It will not show up on under macro names  <kbd>ALT F8</kbd>

There is nothing wrong using private sub if all the code are under the same module-

Now fix your folder Path- **`sPath = "c:\mails\"`** you are missing **`\`**

Answer (score 0):

Code with one or more parameters, anything with something similar to (ByVal Item As Object), needs input.

There are various possibilities to test your code.

```
Sub Items_ItemAdd_Test
    ' with an open item
    '  a mailitem if you want to get to SaveMailAsFile
    Items_ItemAdd ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    ' or with anything selected
    '  a mailitem if you want to get to SaveMailAsFile
    'Items_ItemAdd ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
End Sub


Sub SaveMailAsFile_Test
    ' with an open MailItem
    SaveMailAsFile ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    ' or with a MailItem selected
    'Items_ItemAdd ActiveExplorer.Selection(1)
End Sub
```

You may find a use for manually or programmatically moving or copying an item into the folder.